# Most efficient way to solve SEVERAL linear systems Ax=b with SMALL A (minimum 3x3 maximum 8x8)

Tags: linear-algebra, performance

I need to solve thousands of time SMALL linear system of the type Ax=b. Here A is a matrix that is not smaller than 3x3 and maximum 8x8. I am aware of this http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/ so I dont think it is smart to invert the matrix even if the matrices are small right? So what is the most efficient way to do that? I am programming in Fortran so probably I should use lapack library right? My matrices are full and in general non-simmetric.
Thanks
A.

Comment: Side note: here http://math.mit.edu/linearalgebra/ila0205.pdf at pag 85 it says "For large matrices, we probably don’t want A-1 at all. But for small matrices, it can be very worthwhile to know the inverse." So now I am without certainties

Comment: The problem is, your matrix is not positive definite, it is not invertible.

Comment: Ok sorry I wrote it wrong, the matrix is invertible, it is only full and non symmetric. I corrected my question now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MinLin Correct me if I'm wrong, but the matrix doesn't need to be positive definite to be invertible, anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau When the matrix is not PD, there can still be a solution, but the matrix is not invertible. Only pseudo invertible.

Comment: @MinLin Never heard about this relation between regularity and positive definiteness. Have you got a short proof (or at least a link to an explanation)?

Comment: @MinLin Counter-example: `diag(-1)` is not positive-definite (it's even negative-definite), but is clearly invertible (being its own inverse).

Comment: @MinLin Oh damn, just read that his matrices are non-symmetric, overread that at first. Ok, in this case nothing aplies at all, since *no* non-symmetric matrix is invertible, anyway.

Comment: What nonsense! Here's a matrix that's not symmetric and is invertible: `[1 1; 0 1]`. You can tell it's invertible by visualising it as a linear transformation over R^2: it's a bijection.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: I didn't look into this extensively, but I have some experience I am happy to share.

In my experience, the fastest way to solve a 3x3 system is to basically use [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). If you need to solve multiple systems with the same matrix A, it pays to pre-compute the inverse of A. This is only true for 2x2 and 3x3.

If you have to solve multiple 4x4 systems with the same matrix, then again using the inverse is noticeably faster than the forward and back-substitution of LU. I seem to remember that it uses less operations, and in practice the difference is even more (again, in my experience). As the matrix size grows, the difference shrinks, and asymptotically the difference disappears. If you are solving systems with difference matrices, then I don't think there is an advantage in computing the inverse.

In all cases, solving the system with the inverse can be much less accurate than using the LU-decomposition is A is fairly ill-conditioned. So if accuracy is an issue, then LU-factorization is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. My only concern is what korrok say about bizzarre behavior of the inverse. I did a search and here http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1206090 there is an example of failure of Cramer rule for a 2x2 system.

Comment: There is indeed a speed versus accuracy trade-off, also for Cramer's rule - I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

The [LU factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_factorization) sounds like just the ticket for you, and the lapack routine `dgetrf` will compute this for you, after which you can use `dgetrs` to solve that linear system. Lapack has been optimized to the gills over the years, so in all likelihood you are better using that than writing any of this code yourself.

The computational cost of computing the matrix inverse and then multiplying that by the right-hand side vector is the same if not more than computing the LU-factorization of the matrix and then forward- and back-solving to find your answer. Moreover, computing the inverse exhibits even more bizarre pathological behavior than computing the LU-factorization, the stability of which is still a fairly subtle issue. It can be useful to know the inverse for small matrices, but it sounds like you don't need that for your purpose, so why do it?

Moreover, provided there are no loop-carried dependencies, you can parallelize this using OpenMP without too much trouble.